# It’s possible Read SQLView in COBOL400?

Tags: ibm-midrange, cobol, rpgle

Hi to everyone in world.

In my business we need to repair an old cobol that spends a lot of time in get the data in screen…

I have a little question, it’s possible read sql view using native i/o?, I’m trying but i get a level error in cobol if i use ovrdbf or if i try to compile with view because the view doesn’t have keyed access.

Another method used is using CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE after calling cobol using CLLE and make OVRDBF to that temporary table with the data filtered and this doesn’t work propperly.

The only thing that i have in mind is use OPNQRYF command to filter the data after calling old cobol.

Answer (score 0):

A SQL view is implemented as a logical file, so you can read it using native io.

By level error, are you talking about a level check?

You need to make sure the file the program was compiled against and the view lf have the same format.

Comment: Thank you, i replace in file definition of cobol the view but when the cobol reads the view CPF5129 - I/O IS NOT ALLOWED BECAUSE THE PROGRAM DEVICE OR MEMBER &4 FILE &2 IN LIBRARY &3 IS IN ERROR. ( OS/400 ) in joblog of process

Comment: Did you do as the messages 2nd level text says and look higher up in the joblog to see what other messages might exist?  They will probably be shown as diagnostic messages.